# Code is Making Repetitive call to Data Source

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark, google-bigquery

I have the following code which read data from BQ and submit it to ElasticSearch :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
import subprocess
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


# create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("BigQueryToElasticsearch").getOrCreate()

dataframe = spark.read.format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery") \
  .load("<dataset.table_id)>")
 

print(dataframe) 

print("Loading Done.........")


// Point 1
store_numbers = dataframe.select(col("store_number")).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()  


print("Store_Number Filtering Done.....")


for store_number in store_numbers:

    index = store_number % 50
    es_index = f"store_{index}"
    print("Starting Store Number :" + str(store_number))


    
    // Point 2
    store_dataframe = dataframe.filter(col("store_number") == store_number)
    
    
    store_dataframe = store_dataframe \
        .write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .option("es.nodes", "<url>") \
        .option("es.port", 9200) \
        .option("es.resource", es_index) \
        .option('es.net.ssl', 'true') \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "<user>") \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "<password>") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()    
     
# stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

But currently at `Point 1` and `Point 2` my code is calling bigquery api again to fetch the data , so in for every value in `for` loop it's making a call to BQ making the process slow . How to make this efficient ideally it should store all the data in memory and then do the rest of task.

Comment: Please try to [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) the dataframe after you have loaded it from BQ.